# LINK 1104 cannot open file 'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc16\lib.obj'

Tags: visual-studio, opencv

I will use OpenCV for the first time on windows. I had just added the libraries so I got this error.

I edit the variable's path as follows:

C/C++ -> General -> Additionals Include
Directories ==> C:\opencv\build\include

Linker -> General -> Additionals
Library Directories ==> C:\opencv\build\x64\vc16\lib

Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies ==> C:\opencv\build\x64\vc16\lib

Visual Studio Community 2022/ Cmake 3.26.1 / OpenCV 4.7.0

I really don't understand what my mistake is.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I did it this way;

Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories ==> C:\opencv\build\include

Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories ==> C:\opencv\build\x64\vc16\lib

Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies ==> opencv_world470d.lib